# ParametricNDSolve is not returning results when I use list of functions

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, numerics

I am solving DE w/ parameters. It has many functions so I tried to automate using list but it is not working. Specifically, it does not give specific value even when all parameters are specified and the plot is empty. Here is a minimal example:

```
ylist = {y1[t], y2[t]};(*create list of functions to solve*)
m = {{a, b}, {c, d}};(*parameters arranged as matrix*)
ysol = ParametricNDSolve[Flatten[{Table[D[ylist[[i]], t] ==(m.ylist) 
[[i]], {i, 1, 2}],Table[(ylist[[j]] /. t -> 0) == 0, {j, 1, 2}]}],
ylist, {t, 0, 10}, {a, b, c, d}];
```

I expect the following to give a number but it does not:

```
ylist[1, 1, 1, 0][1] /. ysol
```

Consenquently, the plot is empty:

```
Plot[Re[Evaluate[ylist[1, 1, 1, 0][t] /. ysol]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: `somey=(ylist/.ysol)[[1]][1,1,1,0]` gives you `InterpolatingFunction[stuff][t]` so that looks like it has extracted your first function and inserted your parameters. Then `somey/.t->2` looks like it gives you the value of your function at `t==2` and it looks like your first function is zero when `t==2` with those parameters. Then `Table[somey,{t,0,10}]` gives you `{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.}` Then `Plot[somey+0.1,{t,0,10}]` plots your function with a fudge factor added to get it off the x axis, so it looks like your function is zero everywhere. Are you SURE the solution is nonzero

Comment: For this example, the answer is indeed zero. My original problem is that the code is not giving any result. I fixed it by changing the 2nd argument in ParametricNDSolve from ylist to {y1,y2}. That is, remove the argument t when specifying the functions to be solved. Same thing when calling the values: y1[1,1,1,0][1] yields the numerical result.